# Where does $5$ come from in this case?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, solution-verification

From Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 3ed, chapter 6 p. 425:

[image: img]

For the first part, it is choose 3 out of 11, repetition OK.  This part I get.

I do not quite get the the second part.  Where does the `5 additional items` come from or the number `5` on the red box come from?  What happened to `11`?

Comment: $\color{green}{1+2+3=6}$, and $\color{red}{11-6=5}$.

Comment: Or solve $(x_1 -1) + (x_2 -2) + (x_3 -3) =5$ with $x_1 - 1, x_2 -2, x_3 -3$ non-negative.

Comment: Woah~ thank you!!!